# Where should i place my index.jsp and index.jsp1 for my app to run in tomcat app

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, http-status-code-404

This is what i get when i run my app, you can see the directory on the left. [image]

I tried moving index.jsp in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/src but then my css files are not working.
Can you help me figure out the location or what can be done.

Comment: You put `index.jsp` everywhere in your application project structure but not in the `WebContent` folder.